# Key with modifiers to call certain behaviour in xmodmap

Tags: xmodmap

HW: Samsung N145 (10" netbook)
OS: Xubuntu 14.10
Problem: Backspace key is not functioning.
Want to make Backspace key behaviour be called by Ctrl+Del key combination.
I guess it should be possible to achieve with xmodmap, but cannot find which way can i assign key with modifiers to call certain behaviour.
Any ideas?

10x 4ward